# Why nextProps & this.props happen to be same always?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to prevent rendering of component by using react's `shouldComponentUpdate()` life cycle method. Following is code snippet:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("someArraylen:" + this.props.someArray.length);
    console.log(
      "next someArray len:" + nextProps.someArray.length
    );
    if (
      this.props.someArray.length !==
      nextProps.someArray.length 
      ) {
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
  }
```

But somehow `nextProps.someArray.length` is always same as `this.props.someArray.length` and component always renders itself. Based on antoher component's interaction `someArray` length is getting changed but I expect `this.props.someArray.length` will have previous value whereas `nextProps.someArray.length` will have new value. But both have same newer values as if component already rendered with newer values. Same happens with `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` life cycle method. What would be reason for this behavious? Am I missing something?

P.S :Code for mutating array

```
let someArray = this.state.someArray;
someArray.push(this.props.otherArray[index]);
this.setState({ someArray: someArray });
```

and

```
this.state.someArray.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ someArray: this.state.someArray });
```

Comment: *"What would be reason for this behavious?"* That would be the case if the array is mutated directly instead of creating a new array.

Comment: Added code for muteting array in question. By the way problem is not 'length' is not getting changed but problem is both props and nextProps have newer values of array.

Comment: @Felix Kling , Yes you are right. After creating new array by spread operator it is working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What would be reason for this behaviour?

That would be the case if the array is mutated directly instead of creating a new array. Here is a simplified example:

```js
const arr = [];
const props = {arr};

arr.push('newValue');
const newProps = {arr};

console.log('old', props.arr);
console.log('new', newProps.arr);
```

Both properties are the same because they point to the same array. React works with the assumption that data is immutable and so adding a value to an array would require to create a new array:

```js
const arr = [];
const props = {arr};

const newProps = {arr: [...arr, 'newValue']};

console.log('old', props.arr);
console.log('new', newProps.arr);
```